# Escape strings sent in curl data when using application/json

Tags: curl, json

I'm using CURL to send JSON data. Here is an example:

```
mycomputer$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -d  "{ "some_string": "Hello mom it's me!" }"
     "http://localhost:3001/api_v2/blocks/42af6ab04d9d9635a97f8abec14ed023?api_key=fe5cf0d86af27c086ab5cd4d0eab6641"
```

How can I escape the contents of any value for `some_string`?

For example if someone wants to put in the string `Abe Lincoln's favorite character is the backslash \. He said "I love the \ and single quotes like ''".` how can I escape this while using curl?

I think I need to do the following:

- If the string contains a `"` escape it with a triple backslash `\\\"`.
- If the string contains a `'` escape it doesn't need escaping `'`.
- If the string contains a `\` escape it with a triple backslash `\\\\`.

Are there any characters I am forgetting?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume your objective is just getting the string past the shell's parsing. If so, Use `read`:

For example

```
$ IFS='' read -r var
```

Then manually paste the line.

If it's multiple lines you can use:

```
$ IFS='' read -r -d '' var
```

And paste again, but this time use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to end the input.

Or use a heredoc:

```
$ IFS='' read -r -d '' var <<'EOF'
{ "some_string": "Hello mom it's me!" }
EOF
```

Whichever method you use, you can then just use the variable `$var` for accessing it:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d  "$var" \
 "http://localhost:3001/api_v2/blocks/42af6ab04d9d9635a97f8abec14ed023?api_key=fe5cf0d86af27c086ab5cd4d0eab6641"
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably wouldn't need 3 of those backslashes if you can remove the shell from the equation. Luckily, you can:

```
curl --config - <<\DATA
    url    = "http://some.url"
    header = "Content-Type: application/json"
    data   = "{ \"some_string\": "Abe Lincoln's favorite character is the backslash \\. He said \"I love the \\ and single quotes like '.\""
#END
DATA
```

Look at `man curl`. I suggest paying close attention to the differences between `--data-ascii` *(which is what `-d` means)*, `--data-binary`, and `--data-urlencoded`.

You might also want to compare the different behaviors you get with `--header`, `--data`, and `--form` *(which, by default, all do a `POST` in slightly different ways)*, and what you might get with `--get` which can instead encode the data specified with any of the previously mentioned into the request url following a `?`.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using a JSON-aware tool to create the JSON document.

Using `jq`:

```bsh
json=$(
    jq -n --arg 'Some key "string"' "My cat's useless" '$ARGS.named'
)
```

Using `jo`:

```json
json=$( jo 'Some key "string"'="My cat's useless" )
```

Note that `jo` would try to infer that the value is an array entry if the key's value ends in `[]`.

With both variations of the code above, the `json` variable would get the value equivalent of

```json
{
  "Some key \"string\"": "My cat's useless"
}
```

You may then use the `json` variable in your call to `curl`:

```bsh
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d "$json" \
    'http://localhost:3001/api_v2/some/endpoint'
```